# Facing CryptographicException while publishing an ASP.NET core 2.1 web app

Tags: asp.net, iis, cryptography

I am publishing an ASP.NET core 2.1 web app to `IIS` but i am experiencing the following error message

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key
>   {9bad2257-5a8c-437f-a7a6-ed13f071323b} was not found in the key ring

I have keys that needs to be de-crypted  and now its failing to de-crypt them. I tried adding the machine key on my web config but it did not help.

Comment: Is there a call stack for this exception? Merely the message is not enough.

Comment: you could try to enable the Load User Profile to true in iis application pool identity advance setting [image](https://i.imgur.com/9VLO1BS.png)

Comment: I tried to enable Load User Profile, but it did not help.